# Error(2,10): PL/SQL: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist and Error(2,3): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, database-trigger

I tried to create below trigger I am getting error while execution. Please suggest what needs to be changed .

```
CREATE
 OR REPLACE TRIGGER TEST_SEQ_TRIGGER
                    BEFORE INSERT
                           ON PL_SUPPORTING_LINKS
                    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.ID IS NULL THEN
    SELECT TEST_SEQUENCE.nextval
           INTO :NEW.ID
           FROM DUAL;
  END IF;
END;
```

error messages:

> Error(2,10): PL/SQL: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist
>   Error(2,3): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

I need to auto populate ID column in PL_SUPPORTING_LINKS table while insert

Comment: Creating the sequence might help.

Comment: Run `create sequence test_sequence;` and you should be OK.

Comment: Perhaps the sequence is not called what you think it's called? `select * from user_sequences;`

Comment: You need to create the sequence as everyone here said, but also, there is no need to do the select into  afaik. Just a simple :NEW.ID := TEST_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL should do

Comment: If you're on 12c, you shouldn't even need a trigger https://svenweller.wordpress.com/2016/02/24/sequence-and-audit-columns-with-apex-5-and-12c/

Answer (score 0):

you need to create the sequence by running `create sequence test_sequence;` make sure that you are creating the sequence in the same Table's schema